# Changing EditText in Fragment that is not active

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to change a EditText of one fragment while another fragment is active. However nothing happens. Im doing this through a normal method-call and i suspect it has something to do with the view not being active for the fragment at the time. Though I am not getting any Exception at all. Sorry if I am missing anything important. This is my first question here.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText textView_Text;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.mainView = view;

        textView_Text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        textView_Text.setText(text);
    }

}
```

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    private FirstFragment firstFragment;
    private SecondFragment secondFragment;

    private DateRegisterCallback dateRegisterCallback;


    public WorkRegisterActivity(){
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
        secondFragment = new SecondFragment();

        SecondFragmentCallback secondFragmentCallback = new SecondFragmentListener();
        SecondFragment.setCallback(SecondFragmentCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        changeFragment(firstFragment);

    }

    private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment){
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private class SecondFragmentListener implements SecondFragmentCallback{
        @Override
        public void callback(String stuff){
            changeFragment(firstFragment);
            firstFragment.setText(stuff);
    }
}
```

The callback and everything else works. I've tried using *Log.d* and the information is received by the Fragment. But the view is not changed. 
Therefore i did not find it optimal to also write the code for *SecondFragment*.

I'm really new to Android Studio and can at times find the patterns to follow really linear. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, perhaps not the best, is to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save the text value that you want and then when you show the second fragment, obtain the text from the SharedPreferences and load into the text view.